# Concurrent Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency

So, there is a [concurrent hashmap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in Java, the advantage of which is not to lock down the whole hash table, but only portions of it. I was wondering whether there was such a construction for arrays. Particularly when an array is being resized locking down the whole array is not desirable, especially in real time applications. Anything out there?

Comment: You can't resize arrays in Java, just copy the elements into another different sized array.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the time it takes to create a new array and copy contents will have to be done by one thread, which, if the array is large makes things quite undesirable.

Comment: Instead of resizing you could use an array of arrays: no need for copy, just append a new segment if it gets too big. See https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.7/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/storage/RAMDataAccess.java and for integer it should be safe to write and read *one* value from multiple threads. Furthermore see this ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 6 also adds an interesting collection called [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html)

> ...average *log(n)* time cost for the `contains, add`, and `remove` operations and their variants. Insertion, removal, and access operations safely execute concurrently by multiple threads. Iterators are *weakly consistent*, returning elements reflecting the state of the set at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, and may proceed concurrently with other operations...

Comment: In fact, this is a great answer to the question. The only reservation is that 1) it can only be used for Comparable elements, and 2) the elements are sorted

Comment: This is actually perfect for what I need! Concurrent, sorted and don't allow duplicates. Thanks @gnat

Answer (score 20):

There is [`AtomicIntegerArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) (and the similar [`AtomicReferenceArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html)) that may fit your description. But as noted by Marcelo - you can't resize arrays. So you only get concurrent safety without the need to explicitly lock (on) the entire array.

> An array ... in which elements may be updated atomically

Comment: To what extent is the `AtomicIntegerArray` different from `AtomicInteger[]` though?  In particular, does e.g. `AtomicIntegerArray.compareAndSet` have different semantics to calling `get(i).compareAndSet` on an `AtomicInteger[]`?  The Javadocs don't seem to propose any, which makes this look like merely a shorter syntax.

Comment: I guess that another thread can replace the value at the given position, thus making compareAndSet happen on an object that is no longer in the array

Answer (score 5):

You can always use one of these:

1. `java.util.Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> list)`
2. `java.util.Collections.synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> collection)`
3. `java.util.Collections.synchronizedSet(Set<T> set)`

Your requirements aren't clear.  Perhaps the java.util.collections copy-on-write list or set will do, too.

Comment: This will lock the whole object and OP was asking for an equivalent of ConcurrentHashMap for array.

Comment: I understand it is an old thread but I encountered this while I was looking for something and I thought it is better to highlight. I am sorry but I don't think this is useless. I neither downvote you nor had any other (hidden) intentions.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing in the standard library is the [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). That's 'concurrent' in the sense that there is no lock, and so not contention, for readers; however, access for writers is serialized, and is very expensive. The tradeoff is a bit sharper than for the concurrent hashmap: reads are really cheap, but writes are really expensive.

It seems like it might be possible to write a list implementation which used the striped lock strategy of the concurrent hashmap for single-element, size-preserving operations like `get` and `set` (and perhaps `add` to the end of the list), but the copy-on-write strategy for size-altering operations like `add` and `remove`. It might be rather complicated to get a sensible ordering of size-preserving and size-altering mutations, though.